# Absolute position of an Image in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I have the following;

```
class RpgUI(Image):
    source= StringProperty('assets/background_addition.png')
    allow_stretch= BooleanProperty(True)
    keep_ratio= BooleanProperty(True)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RpgUI, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.build_characters)

    def build_characters(self, *kwargs):
        with self.canvas.after:
            self.hero = Rectangle(pos=[self.width/12, self.pos[1] + self.height/3.5],
                                 size=(96, 128), source='assets/character_maleAdventurer_side.png')
            self.enemy = Rectangle(pos=[self.width - self.width/3.5, self.pos[1] + self.height/3],
                                    size= (56, 48),
                                    source= 'assets/bee.png')
```

```
BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        # RPG UI
        RpgUI:
            size_hint: [None, None]
            width: self.parent.width
            height: self.parent.width/self.image_ratio
```

However, `self.hero` and `self.enemy` are at the bottom of the screen, not the bottom of the image. `self.pos` returns `[0, 0]`.

Re-building in a .kv layout will not help as I need to animate them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rectangles are being created before the main UI (the image) is being created. Thus, the image has no position at first. You need to bind to the screen size update as follow;

```
class RpgUI(Image):
    source= StringProperty('assets/background_addition.png')
    allow_stretch= BooleanProperty(True)
    keep_ratio= BooleanProperty(True)


    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RpgUI, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas.after:
            self.hero = Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=(96, 128), source='assets/character_maleAdventurer_side.png')
            self.enemy = Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size= (56, 48), source= 'assets/bee.png')

        # Update the canvas as the screen size change
        self.bind(pos = self.update_rect,
                  size = self.update_rect)

    # update function which makes the canvas adjustable.
    def update_rect(self, *args):
        self.hero.pos = [self.width/12, self.pos[1] + self.height/3.5]
        self.enemy.pos = [self.width - self.width/3.5, self.pos[1] + self.height/3 ]
```